# Linux busybox shell script html formatting

Tags: html, linux, shell, sh, busybox

I am having a problem with a shell script and hope you can help. I want to optimize the HTML formatting of the following code:

```
#! /bin/sh

cat <<EOF > myfile # temporary file
#! /bin/sh

echo -e "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n\n"
echo -e "<html><head>\c"
echo -e "<title></title>"
echo -e "</head>"
echo -e "<body>\c"
echo -e "<p>Text</p>"
echo -e "</body></html>"

EOF
chmod 777 myfile
mount -o bind myfile myfile # mount temporary on the original myfile
rm myfile
```

I deleted the `echo -e`  and double quotes. I also tried this:

```
#! /bin/sh

cat <<EOF > myfile # temporary file
#! /bin/sh

echo -e '
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <p>Text</p>
        </body>
</html>
'

EOF
chmod 777 myfile
mount -o bind myfile myfile # mount temporary on the original myfile
rm myfile
```

What is wrong with the script?

*Note*: The code above is content of a .cfg file, which gets loaded with every reboot. The .cfg file then pastes the content between the EOF markers into myfile, which is a CGI script.

Could that be the problem?

Comment: Thanks to the people who tried to help.
I should have made the question more clear in the beginning, because it was kind of confusing.
The problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution:

```
#! /bin/sh

cat <<EOF > myfile # temporary file
#! /bin/sh

echo -e "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"
echo -e "
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
        <body>
            <p>Text</p>
        </body>
</html>\c"

EOF

chmod 777 myfile
mount -o bind myfile myfile # mount temporary on the original myfile
rm myfile
```

The busybox shell didn't display the pasted tabs in the vi editor correctly, so I used Vim's `set: noai` command.
`set: noai` solved the tab problem, but there was this extra line after the HTML code.
The solution to this was using the `\c` escape character.

If someone has a better answer, feel free to post it.

Answer (score 0):

No need for echo -e and quotes,

```
cat << eof > shellhtml.htm
<html>
</html>
eof
```

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Very close :-) You don't need the `echo`.

```
#! /bin/sh 
cat <<EOF > myfile
<html>
    <head>
    <title></title>
    </head>
        <body>
        <p>Text</p>
        </body>
</html>
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

Add !#/bin/sh to the top, and eliminate the line that begins with echo e, and the line with the single quote before EOF.  Then your html will be correctly delivered to myfile.

So the correct shell script will be:-

```
#!/bin/sh
cat <<EOF > myfile
 <html>
 <head>
 <title></title>
 </head>
     <body>
     <p>Text</p>
     </body>
 </html>
EOF
```

Comment: I tried this one, but it doesn't show anything on the html page as it does with echo.

Comment: The output should be in a file called myfile.  For me it is working perfectly.

Comment: It's still not working.
What could be the problem?
I really need an answer to this.

Comment: what are you seeing in myfile after you run?

Comment: I used your code in 4 different ways.
I embedded it and myfile went back to default.
Embedded it again without tabs and myfile contained your code, but the html page was blank.
The third time I only wrote your code; myfile went to default.
The fourth time I only wrote your code minus the tabs; myfile went to default.

Comment: what do you mean by "went to default"?

Comment: I think the problem lies with the mount -o bind command.  I am not familiar with that option to mount, is there a reason you are using it, and not just copying or  moving the file to its place?

Comment: myfile is a CGI script (see update 8)
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17735431/revisions)
By "went to default" I mean that the code inside of myfile resets itself, rather than applying my code.
I am using the mount command, because replacing the files in this folder is kind of difficult.